# Converting string with letters and numbers

Tags: java, string, double

So I have a String declared as `String name = "John 20150.00"` and I want to break up the name into a different variable and the number into a different variable, is this possible?

I tried using the `Double.parseDouble(name);` method, but when it runs, it doesn't work right.

What should I use?

Comment: Check out the `String` javadoc

Comment: Specifically, you might want to look into [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: the [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class could also come in handy here

Comment: @Pshemo Or just use a regular expression and Strings support for it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer One thing at a time :) Lets not confuse OP with regex yet. It seems (s)he started to learn Java recently.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh, I don't know, it would provide a flexible solution that would catch more use cases in a single statement and the Op might only be unfamiliar with the Java API ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You have a point +1, for good solution regex would be nice here. But if OP is new to Java I would suggest avoiding regex for now. This task is very good example to learn how to use some of the String basic methods (the ones without regex arguments).

Comment: Yeah, i recently started to learn java around January, so I'm pretty new to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to break apart your string and parse the results

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(name);
String firstName = s.next();
double number = s.nextDouble();
```

You can also take advantage of methods such as `.hasNextDouble()` to test if the next token (the default separator between tokens is white-space) is actually parseable into a double. The `Scanner` class also provides for the flexibility of regular expressions to define your token delimiters, making it very powerful.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! Everything was very helpful, I understand the idea, now I have to figure out how to use this within an Array, and populate other parallel arrays to work multiple names and number values.

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to split the string:

```
String[] parts = name.split(" ");
```

Here we splitted on the space.

Then we obtain each part by:

```
String firstName = parts[0];
double cash = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

you should separate the string into two parts: letters part and numbers part.
Use indexOf(' ') to find the index of the whitespace that separate the name and the letter.
Then create two strings, one for letters and one for numbers using substring().
For details you can check the java api about how to use all these methods.

An example

```
String str = "Hi 4.5";
int index = str.indexOf(' ');
String letters = str.substring(0, index);
String numbers = str.substring(index + 1);
double numbersDouble = Double.parseDouble(numbers);
System.out.println(numbersDouble);
```

Comment: This is the best answer performance wise. This is what i would suggest but then decided on a more "easy to follow" answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can strip out non-number characters using regex before parsing:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(name.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));
```

After extracting the number, you can extract the name similarly:

```
name = name.replaceAll("[\\d.]","").trim();
```

This approach of using regex has the advantage that it doesn't matter if the number comes first or last in the string - it will still work. It also works if there are spaces in the name, eg `"Billy Bob 123.45"`

Comment: What about catching the name as well?

Comment: Regular expressions for such a trivial thing?

Comment: @gtsouk Why not? While I would have tried to split on the name a number personally, reg expression could provide a more flexible solution that could take in more use cases - just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer didn't notice that name was needed too. There you go.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The question is for "John 20150.00" cases and regular expressions are very expensive.

Comment: `regular expressions are very expensive` it depends on how you are using them. This solution can be optimized using separate Pattern class, but it does solve problem.

Comment: @gtsouk It's not as expensive as you might think. We are talking fractions of a millisecond here. You can improve performance by using pre-compiled Patterns, but the code is a little more verbose.

Comment: It does solve the problem you are right. I removed my negative vote. I wonder though how it compares to indexOf() -> substring performance wise

Comment: @gtsouk The only context we have is for "John 20150.00", that doesn't mean it's the "only" use case the OP may need to consider, it's the only information they have provided ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you might achieve this and the method you choose will come down to your overall requirements

### You Could...

Simply use `String#split`, for example...

```
String value = "John 20150.00";
String[] parts = value.split(" ");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

This allows you to break a `String` apart on a known token (which could be a regular expression itself)

### You Could...

Use a regular expression...

```
String regExp = "([A-Za-z]+)|([0-9]+(.[0-9]+))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Which would allow you to match on a more complex set of rules.  `Matcher` includes `groupCount` and `getGroup` methods, so you can access the elements individually.

This would allow you to handle cases where a `split` token might appear within a capture group, for example `John Walker 20150.00`, which you might be able to use `([A-Za-z]+([ ][A-Za-z]+))|([0-9]+(.[0-9]+))` to capture `Jonh Walker` and `2015.00` separately.

You can't (easily) use `split`...you could, but it just gets more complex, especially if the `String` contained other names and amounts, for example...

nb: I should point out, my regular expression is pretty basic, so there might be better expressions that are more flexible and neat better results...

Answer (score 1):

Why just not:

```
String[] cake = name.split(" ")
String a = cake[0]
double b = Double.parseDouble(cake[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to separate the string and double

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(name);
Sting personsName = st.nextToken();
double d = Double.parseDouble(personName);
```

that is what you need to do. The error was because you tried to convert a string object to a number, but it had letters not digits only.

Comment: `String.split()` is preferred over `StringTokenizer`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
String name = "John 20150.00";
String[] parts = name.split(" ");
String person = parts[0];
Double value = new Double(parts[1]);
```